# mysql edit time only from date

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

hello I have a column like this on mysql:

```
2015-10-10 16:30:16
```

now I'm trying to modify the time only from the date so it will look like this:

```
 2015-10-10 18:10:20 (current time)
```

is there any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Yes, RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: which one will do it?